Could not add custom image to my Pin when using googles maps API?
i need to add a custom image to my pin, but Pin element does not except images.
i also need to be able to switch between images based on some criteria, so ill have mixed images of pin.
tried this:
`
<Pin background={'#FBBC04'} glyphColor={'#575'} borderColor={'#000'}  >
        <Image src="/pin-icon.png" alt="Pin Icon" layout="fill" objectFit="contain"/>        
    
</Pin>

`
but got nothing.
if any one can help me find a solution.

The problem here looks like u are trying to use an  component in Pin comp which is not supported directly. Instead try using HTML img tag or any other method that is supported
instead try using something like this


<Pin background={'#FBBC04'} glyphColor={'#575'} borderColor={'#000'}>
  <div style={{ position: 'relative', width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
    <img
      src="/pin-icon.png"
      alt="Pin Icon"
      style={{
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        objectFit: 'contain',
      }}
    />
  </div>
</Pin>



